# How to compile and collate data from multiple workbooks and sheets into one new Excel file in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to compile and collate data from different workbooks into one excel sheet. I am trying to pull data in A1:D1 from two workbooks, Secondtest1 and Secondtest2 into ThisWorkbook. Here is my code so far.

```
Sub collateData()

    Dim SourceArray
    Dim SheetName As String, SourceRange As String
    Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook, sourceFile As Workbook
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long

    SourceArray = Array("H:\Secondtest1.xlsx", "H:\Secondtest2.xlsx")
    SheetName = "Sheet1"
    SourceRange = "A1:D1"
    Set TargetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set TargetSheet = TargetWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 0 To UBound(SourceArray)
        Set sourceFile = Workbooks.Open(SourceArray(i))
        **LastRow = TargetSheet.Cells(TargetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row**
        With sourceFile
            .Sheets(SheetName).Range(SourceRange).Copy Destination:=TargetSheet.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i)

            .Close
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

I have asterisked the line in which I am getting an error. The error I am getting is "Application-defined or object-defined error". I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Still you are unable to solve the issue or got the clue from below shown post !!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `xlUp` (it's a lower-case 'L', not the number '1').

**Edit**

A few points:

- Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules, even if it's not for a production environment. Doing this would have pointed you out the error right away in your code.
- Pick one naming convention and follow that consistently (you're using capitalized words mostly, but you've declared one variable as `sourceFile`).
- Some people might prefer naming procedures using a different convention than the one used for variables (it's up to you).
- If you're opening an input workbook without an intent to modify it further, it's better to use the `ReadOnly` argument, and perhaps also the `UpdateLinks` argument, like this:

  ```
  Workbooks.Open(SourceArray(i), ReadOnly:=False, UpdateLinks:=False)
  ```

  Passing `False` to  `UpdateLinks` will prevent the update link dialog box from popping up.
- Use `Long` instead of `Integer` even if you're sure your values will be well within the range of an `Integer` variable. I read somewhere that `Long` data type has been made more efficient in the recent versions of VBA.

Comment: Correct, fixing the 1 with a l does not correct the entire code. The next error occurs in the .Sheets(SheetName) line. I'm guessing it is coming in the Range("A" & i & ":D" & i) part of the code but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @user1063981 can you tell me what error you're facing?

Comment: Hi I have fixed the error and the code is working now. However I did have a general question. Would it be possible to switch the SourceArray to a folder rather than typing out each workbook? Thanks.

Comment: @user1063981 looping from a folder should be the most preferable way to do it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382861/11774808) should give you an idea.

Comment: This helped, thank you. I now have exactly what I want.